# Is the KCL checkpoint unique for an application/shard or the whole shard?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Given a single stream with multiple shards I assume that each application would, through the Kinesis Client Library, maintain its own checkpoint on the records processed from this stream. However I am finding it difficult to find if this is the case reading the documentation on AWS.

My question is if I had two Kinesis applications connected to the same stream using the KCL, would they share the same checkpoint for processed records? Can they process records independently of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the processing of events scalable and simpler, it is best to keep the following:

- Each worker instance is processing a single shard
- Each worker logic is implemented in a different consumer application

If you keep these best practices, it turns your event processing to be more agile and scalable.

If you keep a worker instance to shard ratio to 1:1, it is easier to scale as you can just add shards (namely split your existing shards and doubling your shard capacity), and each worker instance will only process the same amount of events (for example, 1000 events per second). The KCL will add a worker instance to each of the new shards.

You are also free to modify one type of logic, without changing other logic. For example, if you want to "replay" events with a slightly modify logic for processing, the rest of the logic doesn't have to repeat the processing. The simplest logic split is to a "Slow" processing (put to S3 and COPY to Redshift, for example) and "Fast" processing (going over the events in real time to update counters or identifying frauds for immediate blocking, for example). The KCL will add an application for each type of such processing.

In short, the KCL will help you maintain the status of your processing (checkpoints) for each one of your apps and each one of your shards. If you have for example, 3 consumer logics and 8 shards in your stream, you will have 3*8=24 checkpoints.

Comment: Thanks - the last paragraph answers my question.